# Cannot install ExpressJS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install ExpressJS but its throwing an error.

I've already got other modules installed which is:

`socket.io` & `mysql-node`

But when i try to run `npm install express 3.x.x`, i get this error log:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/3.x.x
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/3.x.x
npm ERR! 404 '3.x.x' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
```

Why is this happening only for ExpressJS everything else installed perfectly fine, i don't know what could cause this problem to being trying to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the error npm is returning

> npm ERR! 404 '3.x.x' is not in the npm registry.

`3.x.x` is not a valid version number

---

To get the latest version, just run

```
npm install express
```

If you want a specific version

```
npm install express@3.4.5
```

---

You should also look into the `--save` and `--save-dev` flags

If your package depends on a module, the `--save` flag will save that dependency to your `package.json` file

```
npm install --save express
```

Resulting package.json changes

```
{
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.5"
  }
}
```

The `--save-dev` flag will add a module as a development dependency. A typical dev dependency would be something like a testing package (e.g., mocha, sinon, chai, etc)

Comment: ohh i see i thought 3.x.x would get latest version for version 3. Ok thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be

```
npm install express@version
```

make sure to use a proper version, ie substitute the `x` with actual numbers; if you want to install a specific version, or

```
npm install express
```

to get the latest.